# google chrome extension userscript icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I installed a userscript in google chrome from greasemonkey. I would like to change the icon which is shown under Chrome>Options>Extensions. How would I do that? I tried to change the "manifest.json" file but to no avail. Anybody has an idea?

Here is the code:

```
{
"content_scripts": [ {
  "exclude_globs": [  ],
  "include_globs": [ "http://someurl/" ],
  "js": [ "script.js" ],
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
  "run_at": "document_idle"
} ],
"converted_from_user_script": true,
"description": "",
"default-icon": "LogIn.png", <-- added this line here and placed png in same folder
"key": ".......=",
"name": "lmi",
"version": "1.0"
}
```

Here is my updated code but still not working :-(

```
{
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "images/KeyLock48.png"
},
"content_scripts": [ {
  "exclude_globs": [  ],
  "include_globs": [ "http://someurl/" ],
  "js": [ "script.js" ],
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
  "run_at": "document_idle"
} ],
"converted_from_user_script": true,
"description": "",
"icons": {
  "128": "images/KeyLock128.png",
  "16": "images/KeyLock16.png",
  "32": "images/KeyLock32.png",
  "48": "images/KeyLock48.png"
},
"key": "....",
"name": "logmi",
"version": "1.0"   
}
```

Comment: Do userscripts even use manifests? ಠ_ఠ

Answer (score 2):

There is no `default_icon` entry, only an [`icons` entry](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#icons):

```
"icons": [
  "128": "LogIn.png"
],
```

As mentioned in the documentation, it is recommendable to provide 128x128, 48x48 and 16x16 icons.

Comment: +1 - but the `Default Icon` is used for the icon of the `BrowserAction` http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html

Comment: I tried this: "icons": { "16": "KeyLock16.png",
              "48": "KeyLock48.png",
             "128": "KeyLock128.png" }, and placed the pictures in the same folder. Nothing happens. Maybe you can only assign icons for extensions and not userscripts?

Comment: @rvmook: Not on the top level however.